# Retrieve default value of in-class initialized member

Tags: c++, c++11, in-class-initialization

Is there any way of directly retrieving the default value of a member, which has been defined using in-class initialization? For example:

```
struct Test
{
    int someValue = 5;
};

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    auto val = declvalue(Test::someValue); // Something like this; Should return 5
    std::cout<<val<<std::endl;
    for(;;);
    return 0;
}
```

Basically something that 'copies' (Similar to *decltype*) the entire declaration, including the default value. Does something like that exist?

Comment: `auto val = Test{}.someValue;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your type is default constructible, you can write your own `declvalue`:

```
template<typename T, typename C>
constexpr T declvalue(T C::* ptr)
{
    return C{}.*ptr;
}
```

which would be used as follows:

```
int main() {
    cout << declvalue(&Test::someValue) << endl;
}
```

[live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/KSgKZce4YCUo9cI4)

This particular case seems to [optimize well](https://godbolt.org/g/TREtW8), but I suggest wariness.